# My macbook pro stopped detecting my wireless router (NetGear DG834G)

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

My macbook pro has just stopped detecting my wireless router!
The model of the router is NetGear DG834G.
The problem is that everyone else in the house has no problem connecting with the network with his laptop or mobile device!
Any ideas on how to solve that?
My operating system is mountain lion.
Thank you.

Comment: I have to say here that my macbookpro detects other networks so it is not a hardware problem.

Comment: This look like a wireless environmental problem. To make it simple, you might be in a dark corner of the wireless network you'd like to reach. Could you compare your accessibility with other computers in the exact same position and add this information to your OP?

Comment: What do you get with:
Apple Menu > About This Mac > More Info > System Report > Network > Wi-Fi

Comment: yeap, no difference!

Comment: I get the same one other wifi network that exists in our area but not mine.

Comment: → Skiabox: Are they (your NetGear wireless network and the one from your neighbours) on the same channel?

Comment: Did someone change the Netgear settings to hidden name ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first step would be to open the folder /System/Library/CoreServices and run **Wireless Diagnostics** to get to the Utilities window (⌘+2) and run a wireless scan to check on your base station and whether the antenna on the Mac is picking up signals similar to your other devices.

[image: Wi-Fi Scan to show RSSI and Noise]

You'll want to inspect your base station (match the BSSID with the Mac address for your wireless router) and ensure that your signal to noise ratio is better than all of the ones I have shown. Ideally, your RSSI should be greater than -80 dBm: -90 dBm is bad, -60 dBm is OK, and your channel not within 2 of a neighboring station).

From there, you could select performance or run the actual diagnostics or see if perhaps you need to select a channel with less interference.

[image: Performance view - shows SNR]

As you can see in this view, even with no wireless network connected, you can run the tool. Once you join your network, this performance view will help you getting connected. Once you are connected, you can monitor things here and lastly, use the Info button to see what alternate channels you might try to let your Mac work with your exact router and the competing devices that also interfere with each other.

Comment: I've tried to run the diagnostics but even these diagnostics need to connect to a network.

Comment: In fact, it is designed to run offline since you can't really assume a network is running when you need to run Wireless Diagnostics. Perhaps I'm not understanding your problem or you're not understanding how to use this tool so I'll edit in some more pictures in the hopes it helps you or someone else with a similar issue. It could be you just need a repair on your Mac for it's software and/or hardware.

Comment: I changed wireless channel in modem/router from auto to channel 1 and voila!Everything works fine now!

Answer (score 4):

It's possible that the WiFi 'channel' option in your router configuration/administration panel is set to 'Auto' and it went to a channel above 11, which seems to cause a lot of MacBook Pro users a problem - for example, see here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5016957?tstart=0

So try changing the WiFi 'channel' to 11 or lower, and see if that helps - seems to have solved my problems!

Comment: Afterward, and notwithstanding the lack of answer of skiabox, your diagnostic seems to be the right one. Typically the router was on channel 40 when the MBP is with a 802.11g card. These "automatic" settings for the dummies are just creating a flock of plain stupid problems.

Comment: Manually changing the channel to 9 (previously 13) worked like a charm for my 2010 Macbook Pro, which was suddenly unable to detect the network since yesterday. Thanks!

Comment: This should be acceptable answer. I was pissed bcz of this issue in my MacBook. Changing the channel from auto to 11 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming someone did not reset the router or made it not broadcast its ID, lets try to use the Terminal to display wifi around you.

Open Terminal and copy paste this:

```
sudo ln -s /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport /usr/sbin/airport
```

you will be asked to enter your computer password

after that copy paste following and watch it work:

```
airport -s
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your channel. If it's channel 12, it won't be visible, and if you're set to auto switch the channels, it could've picked up 12 on its own. Macbooks only detect 1-11 (just fixed my detect issue by switching the channel).